# What does the in-game score in Age of Empires II mean?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

It consists of two numbers, how do I interpret these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first number is you personal score at that moment. The second number is the average score of the team you are in at that moment. If you are not in a team then these numbers will be the same, which makes it quite pointless to show it twice in my opinion.

This only works for teams that where made before the game starts. If you and your new ally for instance both set each other to ally it will update, meaning it will not show the average score between you and your ally.

For information about how the scores are made up: [Age of Empires 2 Score system?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16783/age-of-empires-2-score-system?rq=1)

Comment: I assume they are also useful for gauging how well/badly you are doing? At the moment I am practising my early game and I use the ingame score to make sure I am not running behind, is this the best way or are there better indicators?

Comment: You could scout the enemies alot or make the entire map visible at all times so you can see how they are doing. But if neither of those work for you then the score is probably the best thing to use. Do note that an enemy with a low score could have many units, but barely any buildings. Huns don't need houses, so their score might be lower because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Points are given for creating a unit (based on how many resources it costs) and losing the unit will have those gained points deducted. Same goes for killing units and buildings (based on their resource cost).

You also get points for gathering resources and exploring the map. Also looking at the summary page can sum it up well.

Comment: You get 1 point for every 100 resources you have. If you use a cheat you get 1000 of a resource and your score goes up by 10.

Answer (score -2):

Note that if you look at the scores the computer cheats on hardest levels.    Also by looking at the scores you can see if opponents have a smooth society or going on attack.   For instance I might have a much higher score than opponent but then he castles.   Well knowing that my town is doing better I can infer he is about to attack, or he is about to lose really bad in a longer game.