# How did my ally achieve a higher economic score?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

I am blue, and achieved an economy score of 5457. My ally, grey, achieved a notably higher economy score of 6698.

[image: Achievements]

However, when taking a closer look at economy stats...

[image: Economy achievements]

As the screenshot depicts, I obtained more resources than grey in every category. Not the highest in the game, but definitely more than what grey collected.

How can my ally have more than 20% higher economy score even though I obtained more of every resource during the game? Are there additional factors that economy score takes into consideration other than what the achievements screen displays?

([Military](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3VXI.jpg), [Technology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeqhJ.jpg), and [Society](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h1l7.jpg) scores are included in case they play a factor into it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Economy score is calculated as:

Economy Score = 10% of all resources player currently has or has received in tribute + 20% of the resource value of surviving units and standard buildings (except Castles and Wonders).

If your ally has more surviving units and buildings than you at the end, that could push them above your score. They could also have sat on their resources longer or had been given large amount in tribute, thus contributing to their score.

Scoring system is explained [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16783/age-of-empires-2-score-system) alongside a good example.